# jQuery Placeholder Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML Form that currently has an empty placeholder value.

`TypingEffect()` randomly selects one of eight examples and then calls `type()` to type them out as the placeholder. Then, after an interval of 2000, it applies an erasing effect that will erase it.

I think my problem lies within my syntax, more specifically the `TypingEffect()` function but I can't figure it out.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uxftux9w/)**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="get" type="search">
      <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder='' />    
</form>
```

**Javascript + jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval ('cursorAnimation', 600);
    textbox = $('.textbox');

    setInterval ('TypingEffect', 600);
    setInterval ('ErasingEffect', 2000);
});

function TypingEffect() {
    var tag = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    if (tag = 1) { caption = "Example1" }
    if (tag = 2) { caption = "Example2" }
    if (tag = 3) { caption = "Example3" }
    if (tag = 4) { caption = "Example4" }
    if (tag = 5) { caption = "Example5" }
    if (tag = 6) { caption = "Example6" }
    if (tag = 7) { caption = "Example7" }
    if (tag = 8) { caption = "Example8" }
    type();
}

function type() {
    textbox.attr("placeholder", (caption.substr(0, captionLength++)));
    if(captionLength < caption.length+1) {
        setTimeout('type()', 50);
    } else {
        captionLength = 0;
        caption = '';
    }
}

function ErasingEffect() {
    caption = captionEl.html();
    captionLength = caption.length;
    if (captionLength>0) {
        erase();
    }
}

function erase() {
    textbox.attr("placeholder",(caption.substr(0, captionLength--)));
    if(captionLength >= 0) {
        setTimeout('erase()', 50);
    } else {
        captionLength = 0;
        caption = '';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use `setInterval(TypingEffect, xxx)`, not the string 'TypingEffect()'. You also don't have to call the function with '()', you just want to pass the function, not call it. Sidenote: you can replace the entire `if (tag = x)` sequency by either a switch, an object, or even an array and save alot of code.

Comment: where is `cursorAnimation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to make it work. https://jsfiddle.net/uxftux9w/5/
There were a few issues but I think some were from copying your code into jsfiddle, e.g. `cursorAnimation` variable and that you have not included `jQuery` in the fiddle

The main problems were the use of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) like Shilly pointed out. Use the function name rather than a string like so `setInterval('type()', 50)`

```
setInterval(type, 50)
```

The other problem was the fact that you were using two `setInterval`'s as follows

```
 setInterval ('TypingEffect', 600);
 setInterval ('ErasingEffect', 2000);
```

These will just repeatedly call the two functions without taking into account the any differences in the length of the caption you are trying to type.

Instead I used `setTimeout` to delay the initial call to the `TypingEffect` and `ErasingEffect` functions, and `setInterval` to repeatedly call the `type`/`erase` functions until the caption is fully typed, or deleted. Here is the code. I added comments so I hope it some sense. There are quite a few ways you could optimise and reduce repetition if you want.

HTML

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" type="search">
  <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder='' />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {


var textbox = $('.textbox'),
captionLength = 0,
caption = '',
id = setTimeout(TypingEffect, 600); //call onces and set an Id so it can be cleared


function TypingEffect() {
 // console.log('TypingEffect');
var tag = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);

if (tag == 1) {
  caption = "Example1"
}
if (tag == 2) {
  caption = "Example Example 2"
}
if (tag == 3) {
  caption = "Example3"
}
if (tag == 4) {
  caption = "Example Example 4"
}
if (tag == 5) {
  caption = "Example5"
}
if (tag == 6) {
  caption = "Example Example Example 6"
}
if (tag == 7) {
  caption = "Example7"
}
if (tag == 8) {
  caption = "Example Example 8"
}

clearTimeout(id); //clear first clearTimeout(TypingEffect, 600) call
captionLength = 1; //start at 0
id = setInterval(type, 50); //call type every 50ms
}

 function type() {
 //   console.log('type', caption, caption.substring(0, captionLength++));
 textbox.attr("placeholder", caption.substring(0, captionLength++));

//when finshed typing clear interval and call erase
if (captionLength === caption.length + 1) {
 //   console.log('end type');
  clearInterval(id); //clear clearInterval(type, 50) 
  id = setTimeout(ErasingEffect, 1000); //start erase call once after delay
}
}

function ErasingEffect() {
 // console.log('ErasingEffect');
clearTimeout(id); //clear clearTimeout(ErasingEffect, 2000); call 
captionLength = caption.length; //start at end
id = setInterval(erase, 50); //call erase every 50ms
}

function erase() {
 // console.log('erase');
textbox.attr("placeholder", caption.substring(0, captionLength--));

//when finshed erasing clear interval and call type
if (captionLength < 0) {
 //   console.log('end erase');
  clearInterval(id); //clear clearInterval(erase, 50)
  id = setTimeout(TypingEffect, 1000); //start over
 }
}

});
```

**Update - for those who prefer CSS**

[Here](http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/simpler-css-typing-animation-with-the-ch-unit/) is a similar effect I discovered by Lea Verou done in pure CSS.

Comment: It may be less readable depending on your preference, but you could tidy up all those `if`s with a simple array full of options: `var options = ["Example1", "Example Example 2", "Example3"]; caption = options[Math.floor((Math.random() * options.length))];` Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/uxftux9w/6/

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought too. Also was thinking you could use split on the caption and cycle through the array, plenty of options...